# flask-mongoengine: Generate select field to expose model inheritance in form

Tags: python, mongoengine, wtforms, flask-mongoengine

Say I have this model:

```
class Scenario(db.Document):

    name = db.StringField()
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

class VentilationScenario(Scenario):

    outflow = ...

class OccupancyScenario(Scenario):

    density = ...
```

I would like to create a form to edit instances of this model. This form would have a select field to select the child class.

#### Adding a type field

What I did is add a type field:

```
class Scenario(db.Document):

    types = ((ventilation, 'Ventilation'), (occupancy, 'Occupancy'))
    default_type = 'ventilation'

    name = db.StringField()
    
    scen_type = db.StringField(db_field="type",
        choices=types, default=default_type)

    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

class VentilationScenario(Scenario):

    outflow = ...

class OccupancyScenario(Scenario):

    density = ...
```

This `scen_type` field is sort of redundant because the type information is already contained in the `_cls` attribute MongoEngine added.

#### Using existing _cls element

I also noticed that the `field_dict` returned by `model_fields` does have a `_cls` element, but I don't know how to use it.

In the `field_dict`, all the fields are `<UnboundField...>`

`_cls` is something like `<UnboundField(TextAreaField, (), {'default': None, 'description': '', 'validators': [<wtforms.validators.Optional object at 0x7fe3c983cb00>], 'label': '_cls', 'filters': []})>`

But then, when I instantiate the form, `name` is "bound" (I guess) and `form.name` returns expected html, while `_cls` is still unbound.

#### Is any of those methods "recommended"?

The type field method has been working up till now, but it gets complicated when working with inheritance in embedded documents and I have the feeling I may be missing flask-mongoengine features that might save me some work if not headaches.

Or maybe I'm expecting too much of this flask-mongoengine wtforms integration and I should do a lot by hand.

I wouldn't mind tweaking flask-mongoengine and submitting my changes if they make sense, but I'd appreciate a little feedback to ensure I'm on the right track.

Subsidiary question: Assuming `_cls` in the form should not be used for this, what is it here for? Does it end up in the form because it happens to be in the model but it is not meant to be used there? Does it have any use in the form instance?